# How to mount a NFS share with server user

Tags: nfs, network-share, mount, truenas

I have the following setup:
There is a Debian 10 PC with user A (uid: 1000, gid: 1000) and want to mount a NFS share provided by a server running TrueNAS (12.0-U8.1), which is owned by user B (uid: 1006, gid: 1008). I have to use NFS since this share is used by rsnapshot which needs both soft and hard links. Both machines are within the same LAN.
I found this [forum entry](https://www.truenas.com/community/threads/sharing-nfs-smb-is-going-to-kill-me.85586/), but I do not understand how concretly to mount the share.

What precisely do I have to write to

- /etc/fstab
- /etc/idmapd.conf
- the mount command
- any other config file?

With the following settings I can mount the share, but not modify.

/etc/fstab:

```
server:/mnt/pool/backup /mnt/server/backup nfs vers=4,addr=10.0.0.X,clientaddr=10.0.0.Y,noauto,rw,_netdev,users 0 0
```

/etc/idmapd.conf:

```
[General]
   Verbosity = 0
   Pipefs-Directory = /run/rpc_pipefs
   # set your own domain here, if it differs from FQDN minus hostname
   Domain = dom

[Mapping]
   Nobody-User = nfsnobody
   Nobody-Group = nfsnogroup

[Translation]
   Method = static

[Static]
   B@server.dom = A
```

mount command:

```
/sbin/mount.nfs -v -o uid=1006,gid=1008 server:/mnt/pool/backup /mnt/server/backup
```

The IP addresses are statically assigned by the router.

Answer (score 0):

As kerberos is not involved NFS will use AUTH_SYS, which means that server will use `uid` and `gids` send by the client. There are no ways to tell client to change the ids on the flight (unless you create on the client a user with uid/gid 1006/1008). The `idmapd` is involved only when kerberos is used or then `GETATTR` call returns sting principals as files owner and owner_group.

To fix you issue you have to option: create matching user or force server to map client host to given uid/gid combination. On a regular NFS server you should update `/etc/exports` file as following:

```
/data 10.0.0.Y(rw,squash_all,anonuid=1006,anongid=1008)
```

TrueNAS probably have similar options.